# Python/Scrapy wait until complete

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, wait

Trying to get a project I'm working on to wait on the results of the Scrapy crawls. Pretty new to Python but I'm learning quickly and I have liked it thus far. Here's my remedial function to refresh my crawls;

```
def refreshCrawls():
     os.system('rm JSON/*.json)

     os.system('scrapy crawl TeamGameResults -o JSON/TeamGameResults.json --nolog')
     #I do this same call for 4 other crawls also
```

This function gets called in a for loop in my 'main function' while I'm parsing args:

```
for i in xrange(1,len(sys.argv)):
     arg = sys.argv[i]
     if arg == '-r':
          pprint('Refreshing Data...')
          refreshCrawls()
```

This all works and does update the JSON files, however the rest of my application does not wait on this as I foolishly expected it to. Didn't really have a problem with this until I moved the app over to a Pi and now the poor little guy can't refresh soon enough, Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

My quick dirty answer says split it into a different automated script and just run it an hour or so before I run my automated 'main function,' or use a sleep timer but I'd rather go about this properly if there's some low hanging fruit that can solve this for me. I do like being able to enter the refresh arg in my command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `os` use `subprocess`:

```
from subprocess import Popen
import shlex

def refreshCrawls():
     os.system('rm JSON/*.json')
     cmd = shlex.split('scrapy crawl TeamGameResults -o JSON/TeamGameResults.json --nolog')
     p = Popen(cmd)
     #I do this same call for 4 other crawls also
     p.wait()

for i in xrange(1,len(sys.argv)):
     arg = sys.argv[i]
     if arg == '-r':
          pprint('Refreshing Data...')
          refreshCrawls()
```

Comment: thanks, this is better. I had to deliver my arguments as a list for it to work FYI. 

['scrapy','crawl','TeamGame...

Comment: @JordanWayneCrabb Updated my script to make it so you won't have to manually create a list. If this answer solved the issue please consider accepting it.